# Codeigniter : calling a method of one controller from other

Tags: codeigniter

I have two controllers `a` and `b`.

I would like to call a method of controller `a` from a method of controller `b`.

Could anyone help explain how I can achieve this?

Comment: Even though is not the best approach, it is modular: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091913/1057527)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091913/1057527]

Comment: There is a relevant thread at the [EllisLab forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/55212/)

Comment: @machineaddict 's link is broken. Maybe fix markdown? **Edit**: Ah, yes. To old to do that. :-( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091100/codeigniter-load-controller-within-controller/6091913#6091913 Is the proper link.

Comment: @Apostle 's link is 404 now.

Comment: The link is https://stackoverflow.com/a/6091913/1057527

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is not supported behavior of the MVC System. If you want to execute an action of another controller you just redirect the user to the page you want (i.e. the controller function that consumes the url).

If you want common functionality, you should build a library to be used in the two different controllers.

I can only assume you want to build up your site a bit modular. (I.e. re-use the output of one controller method in other controller methods.) There's some plugins / extensions for CI that help you build like that. However, the simplest way is to use a library to build up common "controls" (i.e. load the model, render the view into a string). Then you can return that string and pass it along to the other controller's view.

You can load into a string by adding `true` at the end of the view call:

```
$string_view = $this->load->view('someview', array('data'=>'stuff'), true);
```

Answer (score 16):

`test.php` Controller File :

```
Class Test {
 function demo() {
  echo "Hello";
 }
}
```

`test1.php` Controller File :

```
Class Test1 {
 function demo2() {
  require('test.php');
  $test = new Test();
  $test->demo();
 }
}
```

Comment: Using require like this with code igniter is not a good idea.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of OOP of CI

Answer (score 10):

```
Very simple way in codeigniter to call a method of one controller to other controller

1. Controller A 
   class A extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_a()
    {
    }
}

2. Controller B 

   class B extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_b()
    {
            require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/a.php'); //include controller
            $aObj = new a();  //create object 
            $aObj->custom_a(); //call function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree that the way to do is to redirect to the new controller in usual cases.

I came across a use case where I needed to display the same page to 2 different kind of users (backend user previewing the page of a frontend user) so in my opinion what I needed was genuinely to call the frontend controller from the backend controller.

I solved the problem by making the frontend method static and wrapping it in another method.
Hope it helps!

```
//==========
// Frontend
//==========
function profile()
{
   //Access check

   //Get profile id
   $id = get_user_id();

   return self::_profile($id);
}

static function _profile($id)
{
   $CI = &get_instance();
   //Prepare page
   //Load view
}

//==========
// Backend
//==========
function preview_profile($id)
{
   $this->load->file('controllers/frontend.php', false);

   Frontend::_profile($id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I posted a somewhat similar question a while back, but regarding a ***model*** on CI.

[Returning two separate query results within a model function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525852/returning-two-separate-query-results-within-a-model-function)

Although your question is not exactly the same, I believe the solution follows the same principle: if you're proposing to do what you mention in your question, there may be something wrong in the way you're coding and some refactoring could be in order.

The take home message is that what you're asking is not the way to go when working with MVC.

The best practice is to either use a Model to place reusable functions and call them in a controller that outputs the data through a view -- or  **even better** use helpers or libraries (for functions that may be needed repeatedly).

Answer (score 4):

You can do like

```
$result= file_get_contents(site_url('[ADDRESS TO CONTROLLER FUNCTION]'));
```

Replace `[ADDRESS TO CONTROLLER FUNCTION]` by the way we use in `site_url();`

You need to `echo output` in controller function instead of `return`.

Comment: But if you have performed authentication on constructor then i will promote a login page so how to bypass it.

Comment: Why should one issue a HTTP request to call a method from another class?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the redirect() function.
Like this

```
class ControllerA extends CI_Controller{
    public function MethodA(){
       redirect("ControllerB/MethodB");
    }
}
```

Comment: if `methodA()` is invoked on a `POST` request, this removes all parameter, including POST data from it. Better is what suggest the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Controller to be extended

```
require_once(PHYSICAL_BASE_URL . 'system/application/controllers/abc.php');

        $report= new onlineAssessmentReport();
        echo ($report->detailView());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the redirect URL to controller:

```
Class Ctrlr1 extends CI_Controller{
public void my_fct1(){
redirect('Ctrlr2 /my_fct2', 'refresh');
}
}


Class Ctrlr2 extends CI_Controller{
public void my_fct2(){
$this->load->view('view1');
}
}
```

Comment: This does not look good - the OP asked about how to use a single method of another controller

Answer (score -4):

very simple 
in first controllr call

```
 $this->load->model('MyController');
 $this->MyController->test();
```

place file MyController.php to /model  patch

MyController.php should be contain

```
class MyController extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function test()
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

Comment: A model is not the same as a controller