# Performance aspect in loading a different model for some action

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I just want to know what would be better between below two scenerio.

I have model A and B in CodeIgniter and two different controllers for interacting with those models, That is A_controller and B_controller, Now my question is i have so many of methods defined in both model A and B. Now i want to use a method of model A in A_controller.

It would be better to load whole model A into B_controller to just use a single method, or should i make a separate method in model B for use in B_controller.

Which option will be better with respect to Performance.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Divide and conquer**

create a small model with the shared functions between models A and B, this way you won't have any duplicated code anywhere. And then you load this new model and the model A for example.

Controller A

```
$this->load->model('A_model'); 
$this->load->model('Shared_model');
```

Controller B

```
$this->load->model('B_model'); 
$this->load->model('Shared_model');
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Create one single model file and write functions, so you need to load only one model in controller. All functions can access from a single model.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer provided by David above. you can also check some good answer for the same

[Codeigniter : calling a method of one controller from other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500022/codeigniter-calling-a-method-of-one-controller-from-other)

stackoverflow.com/questions/6500022/codeigniter-calling-a-method-of-one-controller-from-other